# $http.get request does not work with API level 31

Tags: http, cordova, ionic-framework, targetsdkversion, android-api-31

I ask for your help for a problem that I encounter with IONIC 1.
When I change the API level from 30 to 31 in the config.xml file:

this code is not working

```
$http.get($scope.url)
.then(function (success) {
  ...
}, function (error) {
$scope.errTXT = JSON.stringify(error);
});
```

returns a status of 0.

> {
> "data": null,
> "status": 0,
> "config": {
> "method": "GET",
> "transformRequest": [
> null
> ],
> "transformResponse": [
> null
> ],
> "url": "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
> headers: {
> "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*"
> }
> },
> "statusText": ""
> }

I don't understand why the result of http is null

> Just for information, when i change back to API 30, everything is
> working well. I do not think is a server problem. I start thinking
> that the $http.get is not supported in API 31? My server is running on
> HTTPS://.......

```
 Ionic CLI         : 5.4.16 (C:xxxxxxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework   : ionic1 1.3.1
   @ionic/v1-toolkit : not installed

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 11.0.0
   Cordova Platforms : android 9.1.0
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 1.2.1, (and 16 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : not installed
   native-run  : not installed

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (xxxxxxxx
\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\)
   NodeJS            : v14.16.1 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm               : 7.24.2
   OS                : Windows 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you remove the "android" folder and add it again?

```
ionic cordova platform remove android
ionic cordova platform add android
```

Comment: Hi sanctensys, thank you for your comment.
I already did it many times... but didnt solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

Status code 0 usually means a CORS error.

You can read about Ionic CORS errors [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/troubleshooting/cors).

Essentially, it is likely a misconfiguration on your server headers which are causing your Android app to throw the status code 0.

If you are using a development environment (e.g. `localhost:4200`) then you can add the following to your `config.xml` which should allow you to run it without needing a HTTPS:

```
<preference name="hostname" value="localhost" />
<preference name="AndroidInsecureFileModeEnabled" value="true" />
```

Comment: Thank supper_simon for the answer.
Just for information, when i change the 31 to 30 API, everything is working well.
I do not think is a server problem. I start thinking that the $http.get is not supported in API 31? My server is running on HTTPS://.......

Comment: What framework are you using?

Comment: Hi i put my ionic info in a new question

Comment: Is there any reason why you're using Ionic 1? The current version is 6 and nearly 10 years apart.

Comment: yes it's a company project, so I have to keep the same technology

Comment: Got to be honest, I'm not sure where to start debugging if the framework is so old. It could be a variety of issues that have long since been fixed and released. I'd still have my money on CORS issues though. When was the last time you updated it prior to this?

Comment: Same problem here. On API 30 it worked, but then I updated to 31 (and Cordova-Android 11) and it stopped working. I am quite sure I have the server set up correctly. I handle both the pre-flight request and the actual POST request and there are all the required headers. Used to work like that for ages. This has to be client side. Also looking at the Wireshark capture, the request never really reaches the server...

Comment: This did the trick for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74991697/cordova-this-http-get-request-does-not-work-with-api-level-31-it-was-workin