# Cordova - this.http.get() request does not work with API level 31( It was working in API level 30)

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio, cordova, cordova-plugins

I need your help friends a problem that I encounter with Cordova 10.1.2(. When I change the API level from 30 to 31 in the config.xml file:

this code is not working

```js
  $.ajax({url: "#URL"
                , type: 'GET'
                , async: false
                , success: function (result) {
                    LOGGER.info('result ', result);
                }
                , complete: function (xhr, status) {
                   
                }
            });
```

HTTP Not working, HTTPS working, Please help me to work HTTP.

Answer (score 1):

I believe, http support was dropped in cordova-android-10.0.0 and then reinstated in cordova-android-10.1.0. But you need to explicitly add it in your config.xml, I believe it is this preference (but I am not 100% sure, let me know if it doesn't work, we have a couple of other preferences related to this):

`<preference name="scheme" value="http" />`

Update docs(also checkout the one where support is removed, i.e. 10.0.0): https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2021/08/16/cordova-android-10.1.0.html

By the way, if https is working, why would you want to use http?

Also, consider migrating to the fetch-api: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API. this is a more modern way of doing this.

Comment: Thanks, you saved my day... And yes, that preference is enough to get it working again. In my case cordova-android-11.0.0